# Keyboard hiding textfield in iPad

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Hi I had a problem that keyboard hiding  `UITextField` in `UIScrollView`.

For that I used some code from apple documents.

In ViewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
 - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
 {
     int rowNumber=(selectetTxtfld.tag-1)/7;
     if (rowNumber>2) {
         NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
         CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
         CGRect bkgndRect = selectetTxtfld.superview.frame;
         bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
         [selectetTxtfld.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
         [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, selectetTxtfld.frame.origin.y-200) animated:YES];
     }

}
```

and

```
 - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
 {   
     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
     scrlView.contentInset = contentInsets;
     scrlView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
     scrlView.contentOffset=CGPointZero;
}
```

now it is working fine.
But  I heard that in code line

```
  [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, selectetTxtfld.frame.origin.y-200) animated:YES];
```

for the height of keyboard I am using 200.If I used like this the apple will reject the app.  Is that right or not.

I tried this code also. But not showing the textfields and content of the scrllview

```
    [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, selectetTxtfld.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
```

in my app I am using the orientation

```
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
 }
```

So please help me how to use the key board height.

Comment: You should not use fixed pixel for keyboard height. Instead, you should obtain the keyboard height by `CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;`

Comment: i updated my question.Pls go through again once

Comment: i used  [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, selectetTxtfld.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];  .But the value of kbSize.height returns 1024.Thats way the active textfield not showing

Comment: if i use code like this    [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, (selectetTxtfld.frame.origin.y+150)-kbSize.width) animated:YES];        Then will apple will regect my app or not?

Comment: sudheer, I know you asked me in another question to look at this one but you should be aware that I'm not really an iOS developer, I just know a _little_ about their rules. I've done some Android development but you'll get a more experienced response for this particular question from others here. While I often _tell_ people I know everything about everything, that's just because I'm an old fogey. It's not really true :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo,Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

To obtain keyboard dimension:

```
- (void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)nsNotification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [nsNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    NSLog(@"Height: %f Width: %f", kbSize.height, kbSize.width);
    // Portrait:    Height: 264.000000  Width: 768.000000
    // Landscape:   Height: 1024.000000 Width: 352.000000
}
```

Comment: `kbSize.height` is the keyboard height.

Comment: if i use code like this [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, (selectetTxtfld.frame.origin.y+150)-kbSize.width) animated:YES]; Then will apple will regect my app?

Comment: why insist to use fixed value ( e.g. `150` ) ?

Comment: by using that value only the textfield is appearing above keyboard.Other wise it showing under the keyboard.